# if else statement is returning always same value

Tags: php, if-statement

I am new about PHP and ajax

Ajax return data=="OK" or data=="NO" depends on the email in the database
but if-else block returns always same value.It prints always last block like "email is available!" I couldn't find the mistake.

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'check_email.php',
            data: {email:email,},
            success: callback});}
            function callback(data){                
                email_error = false;    
                $("#email_error").css("display","block");
            if(data =="OK"){
                $("#email_error").html("Email was already used!");
                $("#email_error").css("color","#990000");               
                $("#email_error").show();
                email_error = true; 
            }else{
                $("#email_error").html("Email is available!");
                $("#email_error").css("color","#F1F0D1");
                $("#email_error").show();
                email_error = false;
                }           
            }
```

Comment: have you tried to use `console.log(data)` to check the value?

Comment: Thanks,Yes I checked it returns OK or NO according to php return value.but in if-else statement it prints always last block.

Comment: We need to see your check_email.php script.

Comment: if(isset($_POST['email'])){
 $email = $_POST['email'];
 $sql=" SELECT email FROM users WHERE email='$email'";
 $query=mysqli_query($con, $sql);
 if(mysqli_num_rows($query)>0){
 echo "OK";
 }else{
 echo "NO";
 }
 exit();
}

Comment: Could you please attach the result of console.log(data)? You said it is "OK" or "NO", but this is not happening. Paste the console.log result here please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a simple solution in [link](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/conditional-statement-in-ajax-call) Only I changed `"OK"` with `"\r\nOK"`.

```
 $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'check_email.php',
            data: {email:email,},
            success: callback});}
            function callback(data){
                email_error = false;    
                $("#email_error").css("display","block");
            if(data =="\r\nOK"){
                $("#email_error").html("Email was already used!");
                $("#email_error").css("color","#990000");               
                $("#email_error").show();
                email_error = true; 
            }else{
                $("#email_error").html("Email is available!");
                $("#email_error").css("color","#F1F0D1");
                $("#email_error").show();
                email_error = false;
                }           
            }
```

Comment: I have rolled-back your edit removing the link to where you found the information. Giving credit to where you found something is part of the ethos that Stack Overflow is about. Not doing so, depending on the circumstances, result in various negative things happening. People will respect you more if you are honest about where the solution you used came from.

Answer (score 0):

ajax

```
var email = "example@example.com";

$.ajax(
{
    type: 'post',
    url: 'check_email.php',
    data:
    {
        email: email,
    },
    success: callback
});


function callback(data)
{
    email_error = false;
    $("#email_error").css("display", "block");
    if (data == "OK")
    {
        $("#email_error").html("Email was already used!");
        $("#email_error").css("color", "#990000");
        $("#email_error").show();
        email_error = true;
    }
    else if(data =="NO")
    {
        $("#email_error").html("Email is available!");
        $("#email_error").css("color", "#F1F0D1");
        $("#email_error").show();
        email_error = false;
    }
}
```

html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="check_email.js"></script>


    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="email_error">

</body>
</html>
```

php

```
<?php
echo "NO";

?>
```

Comment: there are two things one there is syntax error, also sometimes fully giving all conditions (even else conditions) helps... (it should not but it does)

Comment: sometimes leaving a space after closing tag in php ?> also causes this problem

Comment: $.ajax({
   type: 'post',
   url: 'check_email.php',
   data: {email:email,},
   success: callback});}
   function callback(data){
    email_error = false; 
    $("#email_error").css("display","block");
   if(data =="OK"){
    $("#email_error").html("Email was already used!");
    $("#email_error").css("color","#990000");    
    $("#email_error").show();
    email_error = true; 
   }else if(data =="NO"){
    $("#email_error").html("Email is available!");
    $("#email_error").css("color","#F1F0D1");
    $("#email_error").show();
    email_error = false;
    }   
   }

Comment: check_email.php
if(isset($_POST['email'])){
 $email = $_POST['email'];
 $sql=" SELECT email FROM users WHERE email='$email'";
 $query=mysqli_query($con, $sql);
 if(mysqli_num_rows($query)>0){
 echo "OK";
 }else{
 echo "NO";
 }
 exit();
}

Comment: HTLM     <tr>
     <td width="15%"><h4>Email</h4></td>
     <td width="2%">:</td>
     <td><input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="textInput">
      <span id="email_error" class="val_error"></span></td>
    </tr>

Comment: console.log(data)   returns OK      if email is in database  and returns NO if it is not

Comment: copy and paste the ajax file in my answer above it should work

Comment: you also have extra if (isset($_POST['email'])) bracket at end in php

Comment: I tried all above solutions above  but did not worked. What I learnt is in ajax object if-else cannot be used.   I got a simple solution in another place.I changed the "OK" in the if statement with "\r\nOK" it worked.          https://forum.jquery.com/topic/conditional-statement-in-ajax-call        Thanks for patience.